# Is there a way to Add another Key in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, indexing, key

I want to add another index of a column in the PostgreSQL table.  I already have a primary key, and foreign key doesn't apply on that field.  I just want a simple key for indexing.  The field is not unique.   Is it possible?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/indexes.html

Answer (score 1):

As simple as:

```
-- Add the column first.
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN MyColumn INT;
-- Then index it.
CREATE INDEX IX_MyTable_MyColumn ON MyTable (MyColumn);
```

Name of your index can be whatever you want, but a nice standard is:
IX_*TableName*_*UnderscoreSeparatedColumnNames*

Comment: Or just `CREATE INDEX ON my_table (my_column)` to use the Postgres naming standard (ie the "standard standard").